# Don wait for output exe powershell

Tags: powershell

In my powershell script i have a foreach loop that calls a .exe file. This exe file starting an repeatable command that executes every minute some actions. How can i make it that the foreach loop not wait for the output from X.exe and continues with the next iteration?

```
foreach ($test in $tests)
 {

    & ./X.exe 'test', --test=$test
 }
```

Comment: Use `Start-Process` instead of `&`, it'll return a process object immediately

Comment: Thanks, this opens multiple new windows. Can i run this also in the same ps command prompt?

Comment: *Can i run this also in the same ps command prompt?*: `-NoNewWindow`

Comment: Great! This works but the script stops running after the last iteration. How keep the script open checking for new returns from every X.exe?

Comment: Start the processes with the `-PassThru` flag, capture the returned `Process` objects and then pipe them into `Wait-Process`.